# Rounding issue on area 51 commitment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, commitment-phase

Refer to screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1369/gardening-and-landscaping

Comment: Similar issue on the biology proposal: http://i.imgur.com/0w0VB.png

Comment: It seems fixed: http://i.imgur.com/cyF3N.png.

Comment: Problem still exists in the biology proposal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, we only update the overall commitment % when someone commits or uncommits. But when you click "more info", live data is loaded and rendered.

The discrepancy is due to subtle drift in the factors comprising commitment % over time, such as score decay, or users changing (i.e. unverifying) their email addresses.

We'll add a nightly task to recalculate all commitment scores, and perhaps also trigger a recalc whenever someone clicks "more info" in order to minimize the occasional discrepancies.